# Neo4j cypher queries returning different count result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want a query that starting from a node, it counts the possible end nodes given relation type:

For example this query:

```
MATCH (start:typeA{my_id:"abc"})-[:rel]->(l:typeB) return count(l)
```

works great and returns a proper number, i.e., 500. The same happens with:

```
MATCH p=(start:BusStop{StopCode:"0247"})-[:CAN_BOARD]->(:Leg) return count(p)
```

However if I do:

```
MATCH (start:typeA{my_id:"abc"}) return count((start)-[:rel]->(:typeB))
```

returns 1.

What is the difference between this query and the previous ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a path expression (as used in your last query) is a *list of paths*. This is different than the result when the same path pattern is used in a  `MATCH` clause.

You would have gotten `500` if you changed your last query to use `SIZE()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
MATCH (start:typeA{my_id:"abc"}) return SIZE((start)-[:rel]->(:typeB))
```